# Select columns from table1 join table2, taking very long time

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have 2 tables. From these two tables i am trying to insert records into a third table using a select query with join. However i found that select query with join not using indexes and taking a lots of time, hence insertion is very slow.
I tried to create multiple indexes as suggested in few posts but not avail.
[MySQL with JOIN not using index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839078/mysql-with-join-not-using-index)
[MySQL query with JOIN not using INDEX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933842/mysql-query-with-join-not-using-index)

Here are my tables structure:

```
CREATE TABLE master_table (
id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
field1 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
field2 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
field3 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
field4 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY mt_field1_index (field1)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE child_table (
c_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
m_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
group_id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
status ENUM('Status1','Status2','Status3') NOT NULL,
job_id VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
UNIQUE KEY ct_mid_gid (m_id,group_id),
KEY Index_ct_status (status),
KEY index_ct_jobid (job_id),
KEY index_ct_mid (m_id),
KEY index_ct_cid_sts_tsk (group_id,status,job_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Query:

---

```
SELECT m.id
     , NULLIF(TRIM(m.field1),'')
  FROM master_table m 
  JOIN child_table c 
    ON m.id = c.m_id 
 WHERE c.group_id = 2 
   AND c.status = 'Status3' 
   AND c.job_id = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY m.id  
 LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Explain:

---

```
+-------+-------------+-------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|    id | select_type | table | partitions |   type   |                                possible_keys                                 |       key       | key_len |     ref      | rows  | filtered |                     Extra                      |
+-------+-------------+-------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
|     1 | SIMPLE      |    c  |    (NULL)  |   ref    |  ct_mid_gid,Index_ct_status,index_ct_jobid,index_ct_mid,index_ct_cid_sts_tsk | Index_ct_status |       1 | const        | 65689 |     0.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|     1 | SIMPLE      |    m  |    (NULL)  |   eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                      | PRIMARY         |       8 | r_n_d.c.m_id |     1 |   100.00 | (NULL)                                         |
+-------+-------------+-------+------------+----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------+----------+------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WHERE c.group_id = 2 
   AND c.status = 'Status3' 
   AND c.job_id = 0 
 ORDER BY c.m_id     -- Note the change
```

Needs

```
 INDEX(group_id, status, job_id,   -- in any order
       m_id)                       -- last
```

What you have (separate indexes) is *not* the same.

In order to get to the `LIMIT` the index must get entirely past the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`.  This prevents computing all the rows (before the `LIMIT`) and sorting and only then do the `LIMIT`.

So, you get 4 speedups:

- Index efficiently fetching the desired rows (from `c`)
- No need for a sort pass (since `ORDER BY` delivers them in order)
- The index is "covering" (hence, no bouncing back and forth between index BTree and data BTree for `c`)
- Get to stop at 1000.

While you are at it, consider getting rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Toss `c_id` and change

```
PRIMARY KEY (c_id),
UNIQUE KEY ct_mid_gid (m_id, group_id)
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY(m_id, group_id)
```

Coincidentally, if you had done this, your `KEY index_ct_cid_sts_tsk (group_id,status,job_id)` would have stumbled into the perfect index.  This is because the PK is implicitly tacked onto any secondary index, but you need `m_id`, *not* `c_id`.  Anyway, I prefer to be explicit.

And when making changes, toss any redundant indexes.  For example, `KEY index_ct_mid (m_id)` is useless since it is the beginning of another index.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. As soon as i used `c.m_id` instead of m.id in order by clause, it stopped using filesort and temporary and on adding the suggested index it started using index with where.
Although i am still wondering, if i had something like m.field1 = 'xyz' in where clause along with the current condition, what should have i used for order by clause. I mean, when to use c.m_id and when to use m.id

Comment: And if i have to sort on the column which exists in `master_table` only. Something like `order by m.field1, c.m_id`

Comment: In _some_ situations, the  Optimizer would notice that `c.m_id` is the same as `m.id`, but I guess not in this case.

Comment: For `ORDER BY` to use an index, it needs to see columns in the _same_ table and _same_ direction (ASC/DESC).  (The latter restriction can be worked around in 8.0.)

Comment: Hi @Rick, as mentioned in my first comment things got improved on local machine. But when i pushed the changes on production its still using filesort and temporary (now on master table) and where (on child table) not using index at all.
Can you help me here to understand why its behaving different on local setup and production.
On local i was using mysql 5.7.12, thinking that it could be due to mysql version, i upgraded mysql on production from 5.6 to 5.7.19 but no avail. Local tables has around 1.5L (both tables) records on production it has around 10L(master), 30L(child) records.

Comment: "Not using index" usually means that the Optimizer decided that it needed to look at more than _about_ 20% of the table.  So, it decided that bouncing back and forth between the index and the data was probably more costly....

Comment: So, Is the data the same between dev and prod?  We might be able to figure out the difference with `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` (from both machines).  This Q&A addressed slowness; recommend starting a separate Q&A to address difference between servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you created index on the columns used in where clause?
Check query by adding index on columns.

but do remember if you add index then insert, update and delete operation on table might get slow.

Comment: KEY index_ct_cid_sts_tsk (group_id,status,job_id), already there.

Comment: @money - close, but not quite adequate; see my answer.